# How to handle oracle regexp_like in ssis expressions

Tags: oracle, ssis, regexp-like

I am using ssis for fetching data from oracle.(oracle source component)
in my query i use regexp_like(clmn,'^-?\d+.\d+)?$'). but ssis cannot evaluate this query(expression). when i remove a part of query that uses this regexp_like, ssis can evaluate expression.

How can i handle this problem in ssis.

Comment: Unclear.   Explain the context of how you are trying to use that code in an expression.   Screenshots might be necessary.

Comment: I prefer using the Attunity Oracle connectors, since you can write an Oracle-native query as the Source Connection. Also, I get an error when I try to use that regex, it seems to be missing an open paren somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to the free [Attunity Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors?view=sql-server-2017) connectors, you can define your Oracle source connection with a query. Here's how I tested that `REGEXP_LIKE()` works from SSIS:

[image]